# Start bottom with fixed and then make it draggable flutter

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I want to display a modal bottom sheet at first with a fixed size.
Then the user may drag it up to a certain point and down to the fixed sized or to make it disappear, as you will see in the Google Maps app or Spotify app.

Is there a flutter package for that.

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext!,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return MyBottomSheetComponent();
    },
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    enableDrag: true,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    useSafeArea: true);
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [DraggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by some custom logic. Let's consider the code below:

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      initialChildSize: 0.5,
      minChildSize: 0.1, 
      maxChildSize: 0.9,
      expand: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: 25,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('Item $index'),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

You can use the **DraggableScrollableSheet** widget to create a bottom sheet that can be dragged up and down by the user. There are parameters like, initialChildSize, minChildSize and, maxChildSize which you can set.

The **expand** parameter here determines whether the sheet should expand to its maximum size when dragged upwards. If set to true, the sheet will expand; if set to false, the sheet will remain at the maximum size until it's dismissed.